# VBA sub to format cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell A1 with a number with currency formatting.
I then want to rewrite it in cell A4

[image]

However, A4 no longer has the commas in a1 which is what i'm hoping for

```
Sub data()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A4") = "Daily PnL: " & ActiveSheet.Range("A1") & " $"
End Sub
```

Comment: Your range is currently using the implicit default method of .value. try using the explicit method of .Text to get a string formatted as in the host cell.

Comment: Put the formula `=A1` in cell A4 and set a custom number format: `"Daily PnL:" $ #,##0.00`

Comment: @freeflow - one problem with that method.  Narrow the column so it just shows _#####_ and the `.Text` method returns those hashes.

Comment: Then widen the column.

Comment: @freeflow.  But how wide..... or do you want to trust the user to do the right thing?!!? :o

Comment: You go via a hidden worksheet.  You put a reference to the cells you need in the hidden worksheet at an appropriate width to eliminate the ###### then your code above references the hidden sheet secure in the knowledge that the cell width will always be ok.